# Is it possible to integrate the simplest version of the radiology 2D app in gradio?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, gradio

Here is an app example that segments an echocardiogram: https://huggingface.co/spaces/gradio/Echocardiogram-Segmentation

and here is the code: https://huggingface.co/spaces/gradio/Echocardiogram-Segmentation/blob/main/run.py

they loaded a weights segmentation, and I wanted to know if there's was a simple way to load the model like this and integrate with gradio for simple 2D apps?

thanks so much.

Tried loading monai label models but did not work.